# In "The Faculty", which teacher was infected first?

Tags: the-faculty

In the movie *The Faculty* (1998) the teachers at a high school begin to act weird. We learn this is because

> they get infected by aliens.

While we find out who was infecting the teachers at the end, which teacher was the first to be infected: the Coach or Ms Olsen?

Comment: I modified your question to ask only question. If you want to know the answer to both of your original questions, please ask a second one specifically for the other.

Comment: I don't believe the movie itself provides this answer.  I am hoping someone might have access to the original script or perhaps the director's commentary track from the movie, or some other outtake material that provides the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I personally believe it was the Coach, mainly because if the "infection" grows at the same pace through each subject it takes hold of, then they would all start to show symptoms after the first elapsed time, and as we know from the film, the Coach was the first one to display signs. Ms Olsen helped the Principal before attacking her so I'd say the Coach.

Comment: Interesting.  My logic worked the other way around.  The coach was the first person who was confronted, it seems, on the field after practice.  When he turned, snarled and asked 'what do YOU want?' it seemed he was familiar with the person. Also, those infected often pretended to be helpful throughout the movie, only to turn at the last moment.